Script or GREP for tabs?
I have the joy and privilege of living in a bilingual country. However, it slightly complicates the task when coming to writing numbers, as one language uses commas and the other one dots for decimals: for example, 12.99 v. 12,99.
I have a quick GREP for changing the commas to periods or vice versa, depending on which language is done first, but I hit a snag when it comes to tabs. As some of the work I do involves “tables” (real tables or “false” tables using tabs), some of the numerical values are aligned with tabs using the decimal separator “.” or “,” as alignment marks.
When I translate the document to the other language, I need to manually change all those tabs from . to , or from , to .. This is not a big problem when there’s only one table with one style, but it becomes a problem when there are multiple tables with multiple styles, all the styles not necessarily having the same tab marks.
Is there a script or GREP find/change I could use to change my “.-aligned” tabs to “,-aligned” ones or vice versa?
